# How to display current date by default on drop down list?

Tags: c#, datetime, drop-down-menu

I would like to display a week of dates with the default being today's date on a drop down list. How can I do this?

I was also told to "use class DateTime.Now, and convert the data value into a string".

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me on my asp.net project

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

and this one on my combobox

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now);
```

i'm not entirely sure about your question. is the following you want to do?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that last code will work. May I ask where I put this? Sorry this is the first time I am doing programming stuff :/

Comment: you can put it on the load event            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToString());
            }

            
        }

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
 //Get Start And End
            int delta = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
            delta = delta == 0 ? delta + 7 : delta;
            DateTime moday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1 - delta);
            DateTime sunday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7 - delta);
            //Get Date Range
            List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();
            //Add To Your List
            for (DateTime i = moday; i <= sunday; i = i.AddDays(1))
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(i.Date.DayOfWeek);
            }
            //Select Today Name
            DropDownList1.SelectedItem = DateTime.Today.Date.DayOfWeek;
```

**Edited**

For This Format`(mm/dd/yyy)`

```
//Add To Your List
            for (DateTime i = moday; i <= sunday; i = i.AddDays(1))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i.Date.ToShortDateString());
            }
            //Select Today Date(dd/mm/yyy)
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put it on the load event

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToString());
        }


    }
```